# mongodb sudden spike in memory usage

Tags: mongodb, memory, centos

There is a spike in the memory utilization of mongodb on our CentOS-07 server.It has 64 Gigabytes of RAM.This is a stand alone mongodb instance which doesn't have any application running on it and there are house keeping scripts enabled to keep only the relevant data .We haven't indexed the data .The total size of data on disk is 81 Gigabyte. This issue was not seen before we tried enabling replication,post which the the node set-up has been using high memory hence was disabled,we then brought up a fresh stand alone instance of mongo. The memory usage hasn't come down ever since we tried re-starting the mongo server but hasn't worked.Is there any reason for mongodb to use so much memory??Below is a link to the snap shot of the mem usage taken from the site server.
The mongo version is 2.6.5

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lui1Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising. See the [Memory Use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/#memory-use) section in the docs for the MMAPv1 storage engine (which is what MongoDB 2.6 uses):

> With MMAPv1, MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its cache. System resource monitors show that MongoDB uses a lot of memory, but its usage is dynamic. If another process suddenly needs half the server’s RAM, MongoDB will yield cached memory to the other process.

It is also not surprising that the usage spiked after enabling replication, as it sounds like you had a fully populated database and then added a replica member. This would mean that the replica member would need to perform an initial sync of the data from that node, which would require a read of every document which would "prime" MongoDB's cache as a result.

Comment: The server now is just a stand alone instance of mongo like it was before enabling replication..the server then didn't have any memory issue but after enabling and disabling the replication and making it a stand alone instance of mongo have we seen the sudden spike in memory and it caused the server to reboot constantly ,also the memory usage hadn't come down even after two days on the replica member,which is why we disabled the replication and made each of the server a stand alone instance of mongo.

Comment: "it caused the server to reboot constantly" -- now we get to the real problem. You see what I'm trying to say is that MongoDB will normally use all of the memory that it can. The fact that you haven't seen the memory get as high when running standalone is not completely relevant. Eventually the memory usage should grow the same even when standalone.

Were you running multiple mongod on the same server? Are you running on Windows? Were you running other processes on the mongod server?

Comment: If it's linux it could be the OOM killer and you need to configure some swap. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#swap

Comment: We are using Linux.It's a single mongod instance, nothing else other than the one mongod instance runs on that server.